# Codeigniter Active Record SQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following Active Record pattern within one of my models :

```
$this->db->get('names');
$this->db->like('name', $name);
$this->db->where('ratio >=', 0.75);
$this->db->order_by('ratio', 'desc');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

This gives me a syntax error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `ratio` >= 0.75 AND `name` LIKE '%JORDAN%' ORDER BY `ratio' at line 2
```

The full statement being returned is :

```
SELECT * WHERE `ratio` >= 0.75 AND `name` LIKE '%JORDAN%' ORDER BY `ratio` desc
```

I don't know why my table `names` isn't showing as I'm calling `$this->db->get('names');` which should produce `SELECT * FROM names`, is it just not returning in the error?  What's wrong with this statement and what should I do to correct my Active Record call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` needs to go at the end. If you want to select a table before - use `$this->db->from('names');` and then just `$this->db->get();`. So the full code:

```
$this->db->like('name', $name);
$this->db->where('ratio >=', 0.75);
$this->db->order_by('ratio', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get('names');
```

or the chaining version:

```
$query = $this->db->like('name', $name)
->where('ratio >=', 0.75)
->order_by('ratio', 'desc')
->get('names');
```

Using `from`:

```
$query = $this->db->from('names')
->like('name', $name)
->where('ratio >=', 0.75)
->order_by('ratio', 'desc')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! The chaining version makes more sense to me.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Yes, it produces much neater code but it's still a matter of preference so I showed you both ways.